Why isn't my second structure being created?
I created a linkedlist structure and it creates the first structure just fine but the second one ist't created and the functions for it seem as if they arn't being ran.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct linkedList {
        struct Node {
        int data;
        struct Node* next;
        } Node;

    struct Node* head; // global variable - pointer to head Node
    struct Node* tail; // global variable - pointer to tail Node
};




struct Node* GetNewNode(int item) {
   
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = item;
    newNode -> next = NULL;
    return newNode;

}

void insertAtHead(struct linkedList* listPointer, int item) {
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(item);
    if(NULL == listPointer->head) {
        listPointer->head = newNode;
        listPointer->tail = newNode;
        return;
    }

   
    if(NULL == listPointer->head->next) {
        listPointer->tail = listPointer->head;
    }
    newNode->next = listPointer->head;
   
   
    listPointer->head = newNode;    
}

void insertAtTail(struct linkedList* listPointer, int item) {
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(item);
    if(NULL == listPointer->head) {
        listPointer->head = newNode;
        listPointer->tail = newNode;
        return;
    }
    listPointer->Node.next = newNode;
    listPointer->tail  = newNode;
}

void print(struct linkedList* listPointer) {
    struct  Node* currentNode = listPointer->head;
    while(NULL != currentNode) {
        printf("%d ", currentNode->data);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
   
}




int main() {
    struct linkedList* myList;
    insertAtHead(myList, 12);
    insertAtHead(myList,122);
    insertAtHead(myList,1222);
    insertAtTail(myList,24);
    insertAtTail(myList,244);
    insertAtTail(myList,2444);
    print(myList);    
    struct linkedList* mySecondList;
    insertAtHead(mySecondList, 14);
    insertAtHead(mySecondList, 144);
    insertAtHead(mySecondList, 1444);
    insertAtTail(mySecondList, 19);
    insertAtTail(mySecondList, 199);
    insertAtTail(mySecondList, 1999);
    print(mySecondList);
    return 0;
}

I tried to make 2 of the same structure expecting both to behave the same way but only the first one did something, and the second one seemed like it never got created.

You haven’t created either of them; struct linkedList* myList; declares a pointer without initializing it to anything, and trying to use it is undefined behavior. If it seems to work, it’s by coincidence.

You're passing your insertAtHead() function a pointer that hasn't been initialized to point at anything.

Running your program through valgrind or enabling Address Sanitizer when compiling would help diagnose this.

You should be getting a warning that you don't name a type in your typedef statement.  The struct Node definition defines a member called Node of type struct Node in the structure type struct linkedList.  The struct linkedList also contains two pointers to struct Node.  Despite the comments, they are not global variables.  But the typedef doesn't name anything — there is no name (declarator to be precise) after the } at the end of struct linkedList { … };.

"but only the first one did something" Until "the first one" is doing what you want and expect, don't waste time on trying a "second one"... Don't ignore problems, hoping they'll go away by themselves.

I found out my error and fixed it how do I delete the post?
